# Sitecore Azure Search - Invalid field name

Tags: azure-search

while rebuilding the sitecore_master_index the rebuild is taking forever and when taking a look at the logs i found several errors similar to the below.

any idea ? Thank you

> 17064 2017:06:16 17:29:12 WARN Crawler : AddRecursive DoItemAdd failed
>   - {2DEC7F1B-A664-4EC2-9CBB-D661763B952A} Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more errors occurred.
>   Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch
>   batch)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Commit()    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor.IndexModified(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, Object document, IndexOperation operation)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.AddDocument(Object
>   itemToAdd, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchIndexOperations.Add(IIndexable
>   indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration
>   indexConfiguration)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.HierarchicalDataCrawler`1.CrawlItem(T
>   indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, CrawlState`1 state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException
>   Message: Error in the request URI, headers, or body Source:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.CreateIndex(IEnumerable`1
>   fields)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.SyncRemoteService(IEnumerable`1
>   sourceSchema, IEnumerable`1 incomingSchema)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<EnsureIsInSync>b__0()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Utils.Retryer.RetryPolicy.Execute(Action
>   action)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch
>   batch)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<PostDocuments>b__0(ISearchService
>   searchService)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>   Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid.
>   Details: definition : Invalid field name: '301redirect'. Field names
>   must begin with a letter and can contain only letters, digits, or
>   underscore ('_').\r\n"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sitecore Climber, but changing the field name was not an option, i ended up excluding those fields (invalid name, size limits such as Text and Media fields) from the index using AddExcludedField.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from Azure Search Service. Can you try to rename fieldname 301redirect to something else to not start with digits.

Please have a look here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index

> The index name must be lower case, start with a letter or number, have
>   no slashes or dots, and be less than 128 characters. After starting
>   the index name with a letter or number, the rest of the name can
>   include any letter, number and dashes, as long as the dashes are not
>   consecutive.